# What is going on with Visual Studio 2013 Preview and intellisense?

Tags: editor, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

It seems my VS 2013 Preview intellisense just won't cooperate and turns itself off constantly.  I mean like every 10-15 minutes.  Every time I look at Options/Text Editor/All Languages/General it looks like [image]

I go in and set it to

[image]

but it just won't stick and I have to re-do it after 10-15 minutes.  What's going on?

Comment: Are you logged in with a live account?